# Java: Unable to use EnumSet within an Enumeration : Initialization error : Tech Research Talent Tree example

Tags: java, casting, enums, initialization

Error:

```
...
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
class com.evopulse.ds2150.TechTrees$BuildingTechTree
not an enum
at java.util.EnumSet.noneOf(Unknown Source)
at java.util.EnumSet.of(Unknown Source)
at com.evopulse.ds2150.TechTrees$BuildingTechTree.<clinit>(TechTrees.java:38)
```

Here is a snippet of my enumeration

```
public enum BuildingTechTree {
//Name                      SoftName                    Requirements    
NONE                        ("NULL",                    null),
```

--> This next line is where it crashes

```
BARRACKS                    ("Barracks",                EnumSet.of(NONE),
WALLS_SANDBAGS              ("Sandbag wall",            EnumSet.of(NONE),

POWERPLANT                  ("Power plant",             EnumSet.of(BARRACKS)),
GUARDTOWER                  ("Guard Tower",             EnumSet.of(BARRACKS));
```

Replacing EnumSet.of(NONE) and EnumSet.of(BARRACKS) with null, lets initialization work, but breaks my code, due to missing data structure... obviously, but I did it to test the rest of my code wasn't somehow the cause.

Removing EnumSet.of(NONE) and replacing with just NONE, and the same for BARRACKS, and changing all related variables, constructor, and methods,  that didn't work either... (and even couldn't use the contains.all, since is wasn't "applicable to my changed variable"... )

I extended this example, using the second implementation:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/25652/48573

I also tried retracing my steps by copying the example verbatim. added

```
private static Set<BuildingTechTree> techsKnown;

techsKnown = (BuildingTechTree.BIODOME);
test = TechTrees.researchTech(techsKnown);
```

to another class to be called from for testing initialization. and had to change

```
public boolean researchTech(BuildingTechTree tech) {
```

to static

This resulted in the same "in not an enum" error. I don't have any rep, to comment on his answer to point out the initialization error...

**Added info for both current answers, as both solutions cause the same new error:**

```
public class TechTrees {
private static Set<BuildingTechTree> techsKnown;

public TechTrees() {
    techsKnown = EnumSet.of(BuildingTechTree.NONE);       //Using this
    techsKnown = EnumSet.noneOf(BuildingTechTree.class);  //Or this
}

public static boolean researchTech(BuildingTechTree tech) {
    if (techsKnown.containsAll(tech.requirements)) {      //Causes null pointer
        return true;                                      //exception @ techsKnown  
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: See my edited answer for your second problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your declaration structure is so clever it's a shame it doesn't work. But `EnumSet` apparently needs the enum to be fully initialized first. It tries to fetch the array of constants from the enum so that, among other things, it knows how much space is needed for its internal bitset.

Here's one workaround. It uses a helper method that creates an ordinary set (`HashSet`) first, and then, in a static initialization block, it iterates the enum constants and replaces all the sets with `EnumSet`s.

```
public enum BuildingTechTree {
    // Named constants
    //Name                      SoftName                        Requirements
    NONE                        ("NULL",                        null),
    BARRACKS                    ("Barracks",                    setOf(NONE)),
    WALLS_SANDBAGS              ("Sandbag wall",                setOf(NONE)),
    POWERPLANT                  ("Power plant",                 setOf(BARRACKS)),
    GUARDTOWER                  ("Guard Tower",                 setOf(BARRACKS));

    private final String softName;
    private Set<BuildingTechTree> requirements;

    private BuildingTechTree(String softName, Set<BuildingTechTree> requirements) {
        this.softName = softName;
        this.requirements = requirements;
    }

    private static Set<BuildingTechTree> setOf(BuildingTechTree... values) {
        return new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(values));
    }

    static {
        for (BuildingTechTree v : values()) {
            if (v.requirements == null) {
                v.requirements = EnumSet.noneOf(BuildingTechTree.class);
            } else {
                v.requirements = EnumSet.copyOf(v.requirements);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no more initialization error, however using

private static Set<BuildingTechTree> techsKnown;
techsKnown = EnumSet.of(BuildingTechTree.NONE);

causes techsKnown to be null, because it is still copying the original "null" value for NONE, appears to not be a deep copy... Will attempt to make another "converter" as yours just for this

Comment: @user48573 I don't know what you mean. It works fine. It doesn't need to be a "deep copy" because all the enum constants are singletons.

Comment: See added info to bottom of question

Comment: @user48573 That problem is because `techsKnown` is a static variable that is being initialized only in an instance constructor, which presumably you're not calling.

Comment: I was just coming to the same conclusion myself, was going to correct myself, but you beat me to it. Anyways, marked as answer and +1 because, your answer, didn't require me to edit a whole bunch of other code, explained the cause without using abstract ideas, and explained what your added/changed code does. (oh and a complement, even though I copied the declaration) , also, the continued support after answering. Thanks and much appreciated, hopefully many people will gain something from reading this question/answer!

Answer (score 7):

You have a chicken and egg problem. You could refactor your enum to something like this:

```
public enum BuildingTechTree {

    NONE("NULL"),
    BARRACKS("Barracks"),
    WALLS_SANDBAGS("Sandbag wall"),
    POWERPLANT("Power plant"),
    GUARDTOWER("Guard Tower");

    static {
        NONE.trees = EnumSet.noneOf(BuildingTechTree.class);
        BARRACKS.trees = EnumSet.of(NONE);
        WALLS_SANDBAGS.trees = EnumSet.of(NONE);
        POWERPLANT.trees = EnumSet.of(BARRACKS);
        GUARDTOWER.trees = EnumSet.of(BARRACKS);
    }

    private String name;
    private Set<BuildingTechTree> trees;

    private BuildingTechTree(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Set<BuildingTechTree> getTrees() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(trees);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

regarding your second problem: you're accessing a static variable, from a static method. But this variable is initialized when the constructor of the class has been called (which is a huge design problem). Don't use non-final static fields. And don't initialize static fields from instance methods or constructors. That doesn't make sense. You don't set the color that all cars should have when constructing a car. Initialize your static fields statically:

```
public class TechTrees {
    private static final Set<BuildingTechTree> TECHS_KNOWN =
        EnumSet.of(BuildingTechTree.NONE);

    public static boolean researchTech(BuildingTechTree tech) {
        return TECHS_KNOWN.containsAll(tech.requirements));
    }
}
```

Comment: This was a valid answer as well, however it required me to extensively change my code. Also, with my final project expecting to have over 100 buildings/units inside of this enumeration, this answer would have split every enumeration into two sections, doubling the amount of lines, thereby reducing manageability and readability. +1 for the idea, I'm sure there will be someone who reads this and finds use for it. and for the response and detailed explanation for my second problem