# How to restrict status transition values to only valid values in Java?

Tags: java, algorithm, design-patterns

I have to implement a status transition validation, like:

```
'P' -> 'W' -> 'M' -> 'F' -> 'G'
'P' -> 'I' -> 'B' -> 'M' -> 'F' -> 'G'
```

where `"->"` denotes "can move to"

In short, a particular status can move to only certain status, but not other status. As in above example, P can move to W or I but not any other status.

Note: There are finite number of status in the system.

I have read about Strategy pattern, but I did not feel this particular problem suited to it.
What will be best way to implement this in Java 8 ?

Comment: Seems like a state machine to me. What are the states? Just strings or classes? What is this state modeling? Do other classes depend on the state?

Comment: Status are just Strings. Sorry, can you please explain, what do you mean by state modelling ?

Comment: I meant what it represents...

Comment: oh. It represents the Order flow status (for eg. placed, cancelled, on-hold etc denoted by a String)

Comment: Overkill suggestion of the week? Use [Spring Statemachine](https://projects.spring.io/spring-statemachine/).

Comment: And what about behavior of other classes that depend on the state? Do you have i.e. a cancelOrder operation that needs to be implemented differently for each state? I mean, any operation whose logic depends on the state, like i.e. `if state is P, do this operation this way, else if W, do it this other way`, etc

Comment: This looks like a simple adjacency matrix .

Comment: If you're really worried about the design pattern, you shouldn't be concerned about the version of language to implement unless you start a hands-on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My suggestion would be to write an `enum State` that represents each available state and the valid transitions:

```
enum State {
    G(Collections.emptySet()),
    F(Collections.singleton(G)),
    M(Collections.singleton(F)),
    B(Collections.singleton(M)),
    I(Collections.singleton(B)),
    W(Collections.singleton(M)),
    P(new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(W, I)));

    private final Set<State> validTransitions;

    State(final Set<State> validTransitions) {
        this.validTransitions = validTransitions;
    }

    public State transitionTo(final State next) {
        if(!validTransitions.contains(next)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        return next;
    }
}
```

**NB:**

This will only allow for a DAG of state transitions, if you reference a `State` in `validTransitions` that hasn't yet been declared then you will get an "*Illegal forward reference*" compiler error.

I see this as an advantage as it will enforce a valid set of states at compile time, but **only** if your states are *acyclic*.

---

If you are using Java 9+

```
enum State {
    G(Collections.emptySet()),
    F(Set.of(G)),
    M(Set.of(F)),
    B(Set.of(M)),
    I(Set.of(B)),
    W(Set.of(M)),
    P(Set.of(W, I));

    private final Set<State> validTransitions;

    State(final Set<State> validTransitions) {
        this.validTransitions = validTransitions;
    }

    public State transitionTo(final State next) {
        if(!validTransitions.contains(next)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        return next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice approach @BoristheSpider

Comment: Hi, Thank your for your answer. This is much closer to what i was hoping. 
But when i execute the code, like : `State.F.transitionTo(State.B)` , i get an error :  `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.test.State not an enum` This seems to be the problematic line: `G(EnumSet.noneOf(State.class))`
Any hints ?

Comment: Seems you have some incorrect imports. Is `com.test.State` your `enum` or some other `class`?

Comment: com.test is the package name in which I created this enum. I was just testing it (independently) before i could use it.

Comment: @Adhyatmik apologies - some sort of classloader issues it seems with using `EnumSet` within the `enum` initialiser. Have switched out to a regular `Set`.

Comment: @Adhyatmik FYI - I did a search and come upon [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24584347/2071828). Seems I was right about classloader stuff preventing using `EnumSet` in its own ctor.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - Thank you ! Worked like a charm. This answer and the link you posted, gave me a new perspective on enums!

Comment: Nice answer, although I wouldn't rest until I understood how to make it work using EnumSet ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat - you can't have immutability and an `EnumSet` it would seem; it's then a matter of priority - do you want an immutable `enum` or to use `EnumSet`. A most unhappy tradeoff.

Comment: Makes sense, then I would upvote again ... which I cant. Or well, lets see ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There is the *state* pattern, and of course, you could also think of implementing a complete **state machine** yourself.

You specify within code which events allow specific state transitions.

In other words: you don't think in terms of "black listing" (P can't go to B), but instead you explicitly state (P can go to W and I, period).

For further reading, see [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/509234/The-State-Design-Pattern-vs-State-Machine) for a discussion of state pattern vs state machine.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a requirement like this. This is how I solved it. The idea is to maintain an enum and process the next states only if they are valid.

```
 public enum State {
    P {
        @Override
        public Boolean isValid(State nextState) {
            return nextState==State.W || nextState==State.I;
        }
    },
    W {
        @Override
        public Boolean isValid(State nextState) {
            return nextState==State.M;
        }
    },
    M {
        @Override
        public Boolean isValid(State nextState) {
            return nextState==State.F;
        }
    },
    I {
        @Override
        public Boolean isValid(State nextState) {
            return nextState==State.B;
        }
    },
    B {
        @Override
        public Boolean isValid(State nextState) {
            return prevState==State.M;
        }
    },
    G {
        @Override
        public Boolean isValid(State nextState) {
            return false;
        }
    },
    F {
        @Override
        public Boolean isValid(State nextState) {
            return nextState==State.G;
        }
    };

    public abstract Boolean isValid(State nextState);
    }
```

Comment: I think my suggestion is less verbose and has a nicer API.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Definitely agreed. I saw your answer only after I posted mine. Although I would say mine is easy to understand.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But, i think Boris's answer is a lot succinct and closer to what i had initially thought.